# Confusing involving !function_exists() || !dynamic_sidebar()

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am confusing with these code in Wordpress.

This allows me to display `first-footer-widget`.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
  <?php if ( !function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) || !dynamic_sidebar('first-footer-widget-area') ) ?>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
  <?php if ( !function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) || !dynamic_sidebar('second-footer-widget-area') ) ?>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
  <?php if ( !function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) || !dynamic_sidebar('third-footer-widget-area') ) ?>
</div>
```

However,

I remove "!" it is still working.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
  <?php if ( !function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) || dynamic_sidebar('first-footer-widget-area') ) ?>
</div>
```

I'm confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It just that the first condition `!function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' )` return `true` if the function doesn't exist so if won't execute the unexciting `dynamic_sidebar` function.

If you remove the `!` from the second value, it just make it (the `dynamic_sidebar` function) return `false` (`!true` which is `false`) - So, in other words, the `!` on the `dynamic_sidebar` function will just return `true` if the function returns `false` and vice versa.

In conclusion:

```
// EVALUATED AS TRUE IF 'dynamic_sidebar' FUNCTION DOESN'T EXISTS, OR 'dynamic_sidebar' RETURNS FALSE
// EVALUATED AS FALSE IF 'dynamic_sidebar' FUNCTION EXISTS, AND 'dynamic_sidebar' RETURNS TRUE
if ( !function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) || !dynamic_sidebar('first-footer-widget-area') )

// EVALUATED AS TRUE IF 'dynamic_sidebar' FUNCTION DOESN'T EXISTS, AND 'dynamic_sidebar' RETURNS TRUE
// EVALUATED AS FALSE IF 'dynamic_sidebar' FUNCTION EXISTS, AND 'dynamic_sidebar' RETURNS FALSE
if ( !function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) || dynamic_sidebar('first-footer-widget-area') )
```

So check that `dynamic_sidebar` function exists - That is probably why this condition is always being evaluated as `TRUE`, even when you removed the `!` from `dynamic_sidebar()`